# CRM 2011 Team Security

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am having this exact problem (not my blog):

http://crm2011stuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/crm-2011-bug-team-security-roles/

The only difference being that this occurs for OTTB and Custom entities.

Does anyone know if this is truly a bug?  Is there any fix?  Anywhere/Anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Might go better on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tom: If there is a better place, then it would be http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics

It's clearly not a programming questions and at the moment there is no place in the stackexchange environment which would be really correct

Comment: Rollup 3 seems to have fixed the issue (although the changes don't speak to anything about this directly).  The only other thing to be aware of is that a user must have at least 1 security role.